# Needing to add multiple includes to what degree for an SPF record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, spf

My company does not have an SPF record at this point and the domain needs to be configured with one as we're experiencing a lot of push back.

The domain uses Mimecast and Constant Contact to send out mail.

That being said can I create something as simple as this for an spf record to encompass passes for sending from either of these providers:

```
v=spf1 include:_netblocks.mimecast.com include:spf.constantcontact.com –all
```

Or do I need to do something as specific as this:

```
v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.0/24 ip4:198.51.100.123 ip4:externalhostedexchangeserverip ip4:208.75.122.14 a include:_netblocks.mimecast.com include:spf.constantcontact.com -all
```

192.0.2.0/24 and 198.51.100.123 (provided by Mimecast)
209.75.122.14 (what constantcontact.com resolves to)

Any help on how to combine these and not have a stop in mail flow would be helpful!

Comment: One little tip I learned recently: when you go to create the SPF record, add a duplicate as a TXT record. Many of the email testers I ran on my email server complained about this. Personally, I would use your second example, minus the include: sectons.

Comment: So you're suggesting to use: v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.0/24 ip4:198.51.100.123 ip4:externalipofinternalexchangeserver ip4:208.75.122.14 -all

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax for Synthax and examples.

In my oppinion, you should use

`v=spf1 include:_netblocks.mimecast.com include:spf.constantcontact.com –all`

If you use fixed IPs or IP-Ranges/-Subnets, you have take care about changes on these and update your own SPF-Record(s). If you use includes, the provider takes care about it, for you.

**Setup-Tip:**

`-all` at the end of the line produces a hard fail if there is no positive match.

For initial setup and testing use `~all` instead. This produces a SoftFail, but mail is passed. So you could verify your setup without affect to mail delivery.

At the moment both, mimecast and constantcontact use ~all as default/last rule.

The SPF-Record is then:

`v=spf1 include:_netblocks.mimecast.com include:spf.constantcontact.com ~all`

**[RFC-4408](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408) is for SPF...**

If you have a look at [Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-3.1) you see that you have to setup spf as TXT Record.

I saw a DNS-Server, which prints out TXT-Record from SPF-Type-Records in DB. And every Domain I tested resolved SPF-Information via TXT-Record.

Comment: But the point of SPF records is to verify that this server does map to that IP, hence why hard-coding the IP is recommended. Yes you have to update it if your IP changes, but that should be so rare that it's not a problem.

Comment: You have to look at the provider's manual. If an explicit IP is preferred, use it. If not, don't. The provider cares about the correct spf entries of his own service. If not, there is a problem for all of his customers. If you add IP or subnet to your own spf and it gets canceled, you have to care about the removal from your own spf to prevent sending others mails  (claiming this old providers IP / net) . Most providers do not notify customers for such changes.